# How to iterate over a list (splitted string) in Python - for x in string

Tags: python

I have one very large string in which the very same pattern repeats again and again. I need to isolate this pattern to populate it to a SQL DB. That being said, each pattern repetition represents one row in the database

So I guess I somehow have to split the initial string into multiple strings and wrap some iteration logic around it.

**This is the input:**

`data = Foo|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|Foo|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|Foo[...]Foo[...]Foo`

I then split it by using 
`data = msg.split("|")` which outputs:

`data = Foo,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,Foo,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,Foo[...]Foo[...]Foo`

Now I am searching for some logic that can basically iterate over this object to assign the values `A-H` to 
variables and push them to the database per each `Foo` containing.

**What I currently tried without success:**

```
If data[0] == Foo:
x = Foo

for x in data:
    Var1 = A
    Var2 = B
    Var3 = C
    [...]
    Var8 = H

..."use Django Model to push variables to DB"
```

**The code runs without errors but only the first `A-H` object after the first `Foo` within `data` is populated to the database.**

Am I even close to a smart solution or what would be a proper way to make it happen?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Update:** Using @user10987432 approach, I am very close to the solution.

I now have the following structure from the initial string:

```
['1.00', '30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f', '1925323', '343727655', '2019.11.14 21:24:01', '2019.11.14 21:24:01', '6', '0.01', '', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00', '0.00', '100000.00', '< >']
['1.00', '30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f', '1925323', '344377716', '2019.11.27 21:07:22', '2019.12.06 17:14:03', '1', '0.20', 'GBPUSD', '1.29118', '1.31069', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00', '4.24', '-353.20', '<>']
['1.00', '30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f', '1925323', '344377723', '2019.11.27 21:07:56', '2019.12.06 17:14:02', '1', '0.20', 'GBPUSD', '1.29117', '1.31070', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00', '4.24', '-353.57', '<>']
['1.00', '30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f', '1925323', '344377724', '2019.11.27 21:08:00', '2019.12.02 18:38:14', '1', '0.20', 'GBPUSD', '1.29118', '1.29444', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00', '2.36', '-58.87', '<>']
['1.00', '30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f', '1925323', '345200110', '2019.12.06 17:14:08', '2019.12.06 17:22:43', '0', '0.20', 'EURUSD', '1.10474', '1.10479', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00', '0.00', '0.91', '<>']
['1.00', '30e61aec-0f6e-4fa0-8c1b-eb07f9347c1f', '1925323', '345200125', '2019.12.06 17:14:21', '2019.12.06 17:22:45', '0', '4.00', 'EURUSD', '1.10483', '1.10479', '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00', '0.00', '-14.48', '<>', '']
```

But it seems that the iteration does not consider the `update_or_create` part to populate the database with that data.

Why is that?

```
            for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s != "historical_trades"):
                if key:
                    version = data[1]
                    DID = uuid.UUID(data[2])
                    accountNumber = int(data[3])
                    orderTicket = data[4]
                    orderOpenTime = data[5]
                    orderCloseTime = data[6]
                    orderType = float(data[7])
                    orderLots = float(data[8])
                    orderSymbol = data[9]
                    orderOpenPrice = float(data[10])
                    orderClosePrice = float(data[11])
                    orderStopLoss = float(data[12])
                    orderTakeProfit = float(data[13])
                    orderCommission = float(data[14])
                    orderSwap = float(data[15])
                    orderProfit = float(data[16])
                    orderComment = data[17]
                    print(list(group))   

                    # push the manipulated data to the PostgreSQL DB using `Trades` model
                    # If DID exists, update values, if not create new entry

                    obj, created = Trades.objects.update_or_create(
                        orderTicket=orderTicket,
                        defaults={
                            'version': version,
                            'DID': DID,
                            'accountNumber': accountNumber,
                            'orderTicket': orderTicket,
                            'orderOpenTime': orderOpenTime,
                            'orderCloseTime': orderCloseTime,
                            'orderType': orderType,
                            'orderLots': orderLots,
                            'orderSymbol': orderSymbol,
                            'orderOpenPrice': orderOpenPrice,
                            'orderClosePrice': orderClosePrice,
                            'orderStopLoss': orderStopLoss,
                            'orderTakeProfit': orderTakeProfit,
                            'orderCommission': orderCommission,
                            'orderSwap': orderSwap,
                            'orderProfit': orderProfit,
                            'orderComment': orderComment
                        }
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious what you're trying to do - maybe `itertools.groupby` is what you're looking for?

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "Foo|A|B|C|D|Foo|Hello World|Test|Foo|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|Foo|1|2|3"

data = string.split("|")

for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda s: s != "Foo"):
    if key:
        print(list(group))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['Hello World', 'Test']
['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: thanks to your idea I am very close to the solution. It just seems that the iteration doesn't work properly to as well push the extracted data to the database. Why is that? (added it to initial post)